# Seeing a nutritionist on Wednesday. Is there anything else I should ask about?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I'm seeing a nutritionist on Wednesday, and these are the list of questions I intend to ask. 
Would like to get advice of anyone in my position (vegetarian, blood results okay but on the borderline - especially LDL cholesterol and triglycerides, eat a range of food but not too focused on super healthy, don't weigh portions, decent amount of exercise). Also, am I missing any questions that I really should be asking?

*Overview*

- I’m a vegetarian. I eat milk-byproducts, eggs, and all vegetables and fruits.
- Don’t like mushrooms or aubergine/egg plant
- Tofu is OK, seitan NOT ok.
- No allergies to nuts or fruits except for black grapes and yogurt.
- My family has a history of diabetes, high BP and cholesterol; They are on medication.

**Questions to the doctor:**

- What’s the cause for high LDL and low LDL levels?
- What should I do to increase my metabolism?
- What should I do to prolong the time I can avoid medication for either of the above?
- What is the ideal weight for me?
- 3 big meals or multiple small meals?
- Low-fat vs. Low-carb for weight loss?
- What is one nutrition advice you give?
- How can I support my immune system so I’m not as vulnerable to an auto-immune diseases/pathogens/colds/flu?
- How might personal genetics influence how my body uses nutrients?
- As a vegetarian, how can I make sure my protein intake is high enough?

**What do I eat/drink on a normal day?**

- Exclusively use Olive oil for cooking in the house.

*Breakfast (8am)*

- 1 small bowl Cereal (Tresor, Chocapic, and Kellogs… ?) - quantity?
- 1 Sandwich with fresh cheese, lettuce and tomato
- 1 Chocolate muffin
- 2 cookies
- NOTHING
- Sometimes

  - Scrambled eggs with bread
  - Ramen

*Lunch/dinner (1/8pm)*

- Pizza with cheese and vegetables.
- White rice with

  - Lentils: Chickpeas, green peas, black beans
  - Vegetables
  - Egg fried
- Tortilla
- Vegetable pasta
- Lentils: Chickpeas, green peas
- Soup + sandwiches with cheese
- Salad

  - Wild rice, apple, cucumber, feta and nuts
  - Quinoa, nuts, apple, avocado

*Snack (5pm)*

- Crisp-bread with Emmental cheese and seeds
- Chocolate
- Assorted nuts
- Sometimes a couple of beers.
- Patatas bravas
- Apples
- Pears
- Banana

**What should I avoid?**

**What should I eat?**

- Can we define the quantity of food I eat?
- Where will I get my vitamins?  My minerals? My phytochemicals?  My micronutrients? My omega 3’s?
- I don’t want to weigh everything I eat ( we have a scale).

  - Can we define it in terms of units, handfuls, cups?
  - Is it a case of what I eat but less? or changing what I eat?

**What exercise should I do?**

- Currently I swim about 1.5km every day (why is my pulse so high?, what can I do to reduce it?) Resting pulse of 
  68.
- Walk to work (4km round trip)
- Sometimes a regular home exercise
- The rest of the day I am sitting in front of a desk

Comment: It's great you've planned it out!  How long is your appointment?  I recommend you actually print this list out, tell the doctor/RD you have made a list of your questions, and give it to them so they can decide how to prioritize the most important topics to make sure are hit at this visit.

Comment: This is my first visit, and I believe it is for 1 hour. Is there something else I'm missing to ask? I can't think of any and I want to make best use of the time I am paying for.

Comment: Very wise to have all your questions ready before your appointment.  You have similar questions to these but these are some areas I feel are important.  I'd ask for strategies to avoid having to weigh your food or count calories -- as it’s not very practical or sustainable.  Also, what they recommend regarding B12 supplementation (https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminB12-Consumer/) -- as the supplement industry is essentially unregulated if they have a brand they’d recommend.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Mike-DHSc. I'd add to that list of questions. I agree weighing food is not sustainable. It's way too much of a hassle. Being the old-school guy I am, I write it down in a book and update the App at the end of the day before sleeping as of now.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Feel invited and take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Been to the nutritionist, if there is any interest - I'll be happy to post notes.

Comment: For many of these questions you dont have to wait for your appointment. You can start researching online now.

Comment: @larry909, I think the problem with some of the questions is the following: the website one maybe reading will not have detailed knowledge of the patients history, diet habits, what's actually going wrong, etc. I wanted a personal opinion of someone who was knowledgable in this area. Unfortunately, human body ain't nothing like Computer Science where you have (only) one correct answer for a deterministic problem. We, as humans, are very non-deterministic.

Comment: True. One thing to keep in mind though, is that even for one individual person, two different dieticians may have two different opinions.